# ambiguity in package references version

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nuget, .net-assembly

In a project, there are several references to Ninject library which have their version, and the unit test fails, this is the error :

> Message: System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) ---- System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

1- csproj file

```
<Reference Include="Ninject, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Ninject.3.2.2.0\lib\net45-full\Ninject.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

2- packages.config

```
<package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
```

3- app.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

4- references folder -> expand -> right click on Ninject -> properties

```
Version: 3.2.0.0
```

5- Manage NuGet packages -> installed -> 
[image]

looks like somewhere in my project referenced to version 4.0.0.0 and 3.2.0.0
I want only reference to version 3.2.2.0.

how to do that?

what're the differences between these references?

Comment: Your binding redirect says it should be 4.0.0.0, that might be the first place to change

Comment: I am having the same issue except for my binding redirect is set proper. I have tried all the solutions listed in this thread and still no luck.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but I think this insight will be very useful to troubleshoot issues.

In your exception, check what assembly is being loaded. That assembly is the one that is requiring the specific version of assembly it depends on and throwing the exceptions when it's the incorrect version. 
It is highly likely that you've downgraded the dependent assembly. Even if the nuget packages and references might be correct, what matters is the assembly inside the bin folder.

Check if all the assemblies are deleted when you clean the solution/project. if it's not, delete all that has not been deleted.

For ninject, the problem is most likely Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost that is not getting deleted when cleaning the solution/project. It is not referenced in the project directly, but copied into the bin folder.

Comment: I've tried this many times. My problem is EXACTLY the same as above, with the exact version numbers in all of the config files. I delete all the bin and obj folders after I clean the solution and it doesnt help.

Comment: in my case the nugget package  said the rigth version but when i check the bin folder the  ninject component was the old one but after delete all from bin folder its working.

Comment: clearing all ninject.dlls in the bin folder did it for me

Comment: deleting the bin folder is exactly the solution! thank you!

Comment: That was exactly what problem I was facing. I don't understand why Microsoft doesn't solve these issues by themselves. There are much more issues like this in Microsoft Technologies.

Comment: @JonKoeter Did you ever find a solution? I am having the same problem as you.

Comment: @Patrick95 yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem with the same versionnumbers as you had.

There's something strange going on with Ninject 3.2.2.0.

What solved this for me was to leave the 3.2.2 package installed. Leave the packages.config alone and change the app.config to 3.2.0.0. Yes. Thats right. Not to 3.2.2.0, but to 3.2.0.0. This is what the runtime exception is whining about, so I thought I'd give it a try.

So to summarize:

CSProj file:

```
<Reference Include="Ninject, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Ninject.3.2.2.0\lib\net45-full\Ninject.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Packages.config:

```
<package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

App.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Note if you have Ninject.Web.Common as well you might have to do the same for that. I had to change the newVersion from 3.2.3.0 to 3.2.0.0 in addition to the fix in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was trying to find Ninject 3.3.3.0 (and I had installed v3.3.4)

I checked *project file* (.csproj), *web.config* and *packages.config*, and they were all fine.

- I uninstalled all Ninject NuGet packages from all my projects.
- Then went to "Manage NuGet packages **for Solution**" and reinstalled all Ninject packages for all projects from there.

I know it seems silly ... but it fixed it for me!

Comment: I have the same scenario, but this "solution" not working for me. "System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject, Version=3.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add the following node to the `web.config` file at `configuration > runtime > assemblyBinding`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.4.0" newVersion="3.3.4.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject.Web.Common" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.2.0" newVersion="3.3.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

[image: Ninject & entity framework web.config changes]

Comment: Yep this was the missing puzzle piece! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Because I am running Ninject inside a Window service I needed to install
the ServiceName.exe.Config file so that the app.config information gets
properly loaded when my service starts.

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.3.3.0" newVersion="3.3.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

*Install-Package Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost -Version 3.3.1*

Run the above command in nuget package manager console.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to delete all files in bin folder of the solution.